# Javascript bookmarklet to remove navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a javascript bookmark that will remove a side navbar from a website that I use, but cannot seem to be able to remove it.

The navbar element id I would like to hide is is:

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav.side-nav.col-md-2
```

I have tried a few ways from researching online, but with no luck. How can I accomplish this?

Here is my attempt:

```
javascript:(function(){('ul.nav.navbar-nav.side-nav.col-md-2').hide()})();
```

This is an internal portal website that I use.

I am trying to modify/remove the menu once the site is loaded via the browser in the form of a javascript bookmarklet, and am not editing the site's code myself.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without an example of the problem or website it won't be very clear/easy for anyone to help.

But one obvious issue I see is that you are not actually referring to an element directly, you just placed a CSS selector in brackets:

```
('ul.nav.navbar-nav.side-nav.col-md-2')
```

You probably want to use `jQuery` to get the element:

```
$('ul.nav.navbar-nav.side-nav.col-md-2')
```

Or if `jQuery` is not available:

```
document.querySelector('ul.nav.navbar-nav.side-nav.col-md-2').style.display = 'none';
```